# The Keys -a, ESC, tab, CAPS Lock on the keyboard- do not work

Tags: windows-10

Since the latest Update of Windows 10 the keys <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>ESC</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>, and <kbd>Tab</kbd> do not work
at all.

Comment: Have you tried another (USB) keyboard?

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

i find your answer in: [caps-lock-stuck-windows-10](http://windowsreport.com/caps-lock-num-lock-stuck-windows-10/)

i say answer part of this here: 
 While there isn’t an official fix for this problem, you could try performing the following actions:

```
Right-click Start, choose Control Panel
Under Clock, Language and Region, choose Change input methods
On the left, choose Advanced Settings
Now click on Change language bar hot keys
On the Advanced Key Settings tab, select Press the Shift key
Click OK, then Save
```

After you’re done, press the Shift key, and Caps Lock will then return to its usual behavior. Obviously, this is just a temporary fix, until Windows 10 gets officially available.